# Angular Test for the Keycloak Angular Package

Tags: angular, keycloak, angular-test, keycloak-angular

I'm new with the implementation of keycloak-angular package, everything is working but I need to write some test, and it's not clear how to approach this topic, I did some research and I wrote some tests but I need to call the keycloak method or I need to fake it or mock it, but I need to know what the keycloak is returning me when the user is successfuly loggedin, so I can test the login flow.

component:

```
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(private readonly keycloak: KeycloakService) {}

  public async ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = await this.keycloak.isLoggedIn();
    if (!this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.keycloak.login();
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.keycloak.logout();
  }
```

and here are the tests:

```
fdescribe('MainPageComponent', () => {
  let component: MainPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainPageComponent>;
  let keycloakService: jasmine.SpyObj<KeycloakService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('KeycloakService', [
      'login',
      'isLoggedIn',
    ]);
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MainPageComponent],
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [{ provide: KeycloakService, useValue: spy }],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainPageComponent);
    keycloakService = TestBed.inject(
      KeycloakService
    ) as jasmine.SpyObj<KeycloakService>;
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create MainPageComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should called login when the user is not loggin', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    let loggedIdUser = component.isLoggedIn;
    expect(keycloakService).toBeDefined();
    expect(loggedIdUser).toBeFalsy();
    expect(keycloakService.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

App Init:

```
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'xxx',
        realm: 'xxx',
        clientId: 'xxx',
      },
      loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false,
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        checkLoginIframe: false,
      },
    });
}
```

if some can show me the way, because I can't find too much about this topic. :)